# Как создать надежный и анонимный удаленный рабочий стол для подключения к сайту из другой страны?

Tags: хостинг, vds, прокси

Я в России. Мне необходимо подключиться и авторизоваться на сайте, который не работает в России и поддержка банит тех, кто выдает своё местоположение. Я хочу подключиться туда из Латвии.

1. Платный ВПН для Windows. Использую браузер firefox, на котором всегда подчищаю куки для работы с этим сайтом (а обычно для себя юзаю Хром). Подключение есть, но саппорт написал мне, что видит что я использую ВПН, анонимайзер и чтобы я больше этого не делал.
2. Купил прокси на сайте proxy-seller.ru Через программу proxifier я включил работу firefox с этим прокси, захожу для проверки на whoer.com, там написано что все в порядке, анонимность 90-100%, далее захожу на мой сайт, авторизуюсь и мне это запрещено! Пишут, что я в России и мой айпишник реальный:(( А пару лет назад с этими прокси я вполне работал. Кроме того, в proxifier видно, что соединение не стабильное(
3. Вариант с удаленным компьютером/сервером. Это ведь самый надежный вариант, или нет?
   Я купил такой сервер на сайте 4vps.su

   Тариф, конфигурация
   Ядра ЦПУ
   1 vCPU
   (3.6 GHz)
   RAM
   2 GB DDR4
   Объём диска
   20 GB NVMe
   Тариф
   LV-cx11
   ОС
   Windows 10 RUS

Я впервые делаю это.. подключился через WIN+R , самое подключение долгое и не с первого раза, там я сразу через Edge зашел на Whoer и увидел:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-первых там имя хоста - это моё имя сервера, которое я задал и это палево. Я имя сервера изменил, перезагрузил его, но на whoer оно так и показывает старое.
Во-вторых: имя провайдера Global Internet Solutions - это же тоже палево? Они там поймут что я удаленно пытаюсь работать и не нахожусь физически в Латвии?

Вопрос: какой способ выбрать для надежной, стабильной и анонимной работы? Где приобрести удаленный доступ? Спасибо.

Comment: Некоторые люди говорят, что заграничные адреса на выбранном вами хостинге (4vps) на самом деле не заграничные. Не уверен, как они это делают, но такое встречается. Сам попадался на похожую ситуацию, правда на другом хостинге. Первое время все работает нормально, но потом сайты начинают "догадываться"

Comment: IP-адрес не residential — сразу подозрительно

Answer (score 1):

по 3 варианту,

1. Имя хоста можно изменить в панели управления, на любое.
2. Наоборот Global Internet Solutions - международный провайдер.

Comment: Вы что специально зарегистрировались?\